# Prove $\log x≤x-1 \forall x>0$ with the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove $\log x≤x-1 \forall x>0$ using the mean value theorem. I exponentiate both sides to get $x≤e^{x-1}$. Let $f(x)=e^{x-1}-x$. I want to prove $f(x)≥0$. On $(0,x)$ there exists a $c$ such that $f(x)-f(0)=f'(c)x$ or $f(x)=(e^{c-1}-1)x+1/e$. Since $c>0$, $e^{c-1}>1/e$ so $f(x)>(1/e-1)x+1/e>0$. This is not showing the inequality, how can I proceed?

Comment: The mean value theorem for integrals applied to $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$ works in case that's allowed

Comment: I am not familiar with that...

Comment: $\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(c) (b-a)$

Comment: We are not allowed to use integrals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you apply your own idea to the original problem, $g(x)=x-1-\log x\ge0$? If $x>1$, $g(x)=g(x)-g(1)=g'(c)(x-1)=(1-1/c)(x-1)\ge0$, because $c\ge1$. If $x<1$, both factors are non-positive (then, $c\le1$), and the argument is still valid.